# How to check if datetime equal tomorrow in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I want to retrieve mysql table data if the data `created_at` Datetime column equal to tomorrow date, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_order where created_at = tomorrow_date;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use search function!
You can use `CURDATE() + 1` or `NOW() + 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales_order 
WHERE DATEDIFF(created_at, DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 0;
```

or a simpler solution only using [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales_order 
WHERE DATEDIFF(created_at, CURDATE()) = 1
```

> `DATEDIFF()` returns ***`expr1 − expr2`*** expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. ***`expr1`*** and ***`expr2`*** are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation. - [from MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sales_order where created_at = CURDATE() + 1;
```